# Directional Arrow Marker in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, icons, android-drawable, marker

I am trying to find the **directional arrow head marker** drawable icon (used in Google Maps) but for the love of me cannot find it or much info on the matter.

The marker in question is this one:

[image: Arrow Head Marker]

I am guessing this arrow head should be available in the built-in Android drawables? Or alternatively, a link to the icon would also suffice.

Comment: I dont think it is available in the built in android drawables..All the drawables can be found out from `\sdk\platforms`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Try this]

The image you are asking for, i created it a while back.
Check this out

Comment: @AA it's awesome! I defiantly voted your answer but unfortunately i exceeds my today's vote limit.